# Getting an output from Python that gets executed by PHP

Tags: python, php, linux, amazon-web-services, apache2

So my issue is that I have an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu server 18.04 and Apache2, when a button is pressed it posts some variables which are passed to a function which then uses shell_exec() to execute a Python script. The Python script then takes these variables (direction and angle) as command line arguments, it will then attempt to write then to a file called cmds.txt. When doing this however I get this error reported back to me:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/server/cmdWriter.py", line 45, in 
    main()
  File "/home/server/cmdWriter.py", line 41, in main
    servoCmds(direction, angle)
  File "/home/server/cmdWriter.py", line 28, in servoCmds
    cmdFile = open("cmds.txt", "a")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'cmds.txt'
```

After some looking I think this is because PHP executes as user "www-data" which doesn't have write privileges, so after looking at other questions I tried settung up permissions so that www-data has read and write privilages to the folder and the python file. For whatever reason this does not work! I've been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work, trying suggestions from several other questions, can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error with respect to 'opening' the file.  You have to make sure that the permissions on the .txt file are at 755 or higher.  If the server you are using is Linux, then you have two alternatives to modify the permissions:

1. If you have cPanel, you can use the cPanel interface and just change permissions by going to the file, click on Change Permissions and then set the permissions to 777.

or

2. From the linux command line, use chmod command - like this:

```
chmod 777 cmds.txt
```

I can't speak to the security issues associated with same without knowing more.

The other possibility is that you are using the 'a' mode, but the file does not already exist.  If you are not certain the file exists when the command is executed, you may try 'a+' as that will create the file if one does not already exist.

Does that work?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reponse. Just tried it again and same result sadly. I've also tried using chown to make the python file and the folder it is in to be owned by www-data but also same result.

Comment: Hmmm, I use the same technique on my server so not sure what the issue is.  Can you try just a test case where you cause your PhP to shell_exec your Python script and your Python script simply writes text to a NEW text file?  Can you try that and see if that works?

Comment: Ok so set this up:

Python file located in /home/server:

`import sys
file = open("test.txt", "a+")
file.write("Test")
file.close()`

PHP file located in /var/www/html:

`<?php
$cmd = "python3 /home/server/test.py 2 2>&1";
echo "Cmd: " . $cmd;
$out = shell_exec($cmd);
echo "<pre>$out</pre>";
?>`

Still same issue.

Comment: Why are you putting "python 3 " immediately before your filepath?  Shouldn't it be (ignoring the use of $cmd variable) $out = shell_exec("/home/server/test.py")?

Comment: Ah thats because I thought you had to to tell it to run the python script, just tested it without it and still get permission denied.

Comment: What about just ignoring PhP for the moment and just executing your .py file from the Linux command line.  Can you get your .py file to open the .txt file WITHOUT regard to PhP?  In other words, I am trying to isolate whether this is a PhP/Python issue or whether the server you are working on simply doesn't let you write to any file.

Comment: I've actually just figured it out, turns out Python was trying to create the .txt file in /var/www/html which the user www-data DID NOT have permission to write to, I did `chmod 777 /var/www/html/` and it works! I do know its unsecure to do this but it works.

Comment: Great.  Glad to hear it!